# import to mysql5.7.17 old version mysql5.1 mysqldump

Tags: mysql

http://mysqlserverteam.com/upgrading-directly-from-mysql-5-0-to-5-7-with-

I think no matter there import old dump to new version 5.7.17 and do mysql_upgrade. That also safety method .

The article was written 2 years ago.
I wonder if even now I must do like that upgrade step by step?

Comment: Maybe? Possibly? Try it on a test server and find out. It normally depends on what database features you've made use of. I've had migrations that were painless, others that were a pain in the butt.

Comment: so ,do you mean not enough mysql_upgrade

Comment: I mean if you're using features that were removed or fundamentally changed you will have problems, but if it's just basic table data you're probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  Take a dump of 5.1 data (with a new `mysqldump` if practical).  Then load it onto a freshly installed 5.7.

Plan B:  Upgrade in place 5.5, run its `mysql_upgrade`, and test.  Repeat to get to 5.6.  Repeat again to 5.7.  Each time you would be running a new mysql_upgrade.

Since there are 3 "major" upgrades, there are many things that *might* cause hiccups (with either Plan).  Or it might go smoothly.

The article is an old one, and the advice had not changed substantively in perhaps 15 years.